# How do I set \r or CR as End of Line in Git?

Tags: git, carriage-return, line-endings, ti-basic, gitattributes

I'm adding my TI-89 programs to a Git repository and they all use \r line endings like [Mac OS](https://superuser.com/questions/439440/did-mac-os-lion-switch-to-using-line-feeds-lf-n-for-line-breaks-instead-of) (before X). Is it possible to set the line endings in `.gitattributes` to carriage return? Here's my file so far:

```
*.89p diff eol=cr
```

Is it possible to version files in Git as though they were Mac OS 9 files? Or is it not supported because Git came out 5 years after \r line endings faded from the mainstream?

Comment: Thank you! I searched for a while but I couldn't find the linked question.